# How to check column is virtual in Oracle?

Tags: sql, oracle

How to check if a column is virtual in Oracle?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

You can use the `VIRTUAL_COLUMN` column of `USER_TAB_COLS` (or `ALL_TAB_COLS` or `DBA_TAB_COLS` depending on what privileges you have and what user owns the table in question.

```
SELECT virtual_column
  FROM all_tab_cols
 WHERE owner = <<owner of the table>>
   AND table_name = <<name of table>>
   AND column_name = <<name of column>>
```

Comment: I´ve only found the `VIRTUAL_COLUMN` column in the `ALL_TAB_COLS` table - tables `USER_TAB_COLS` & `DBA_TAB_COLS` do not seem to have them (using Oracle 19.2)