# is there any way to check if a column is virtual in java?

Tags: java, database, oracle, jdbc, virtual-column

I want to know if there is any way to check if a column in a table is virtual in java?
I was trying the ResultSetMetaData no luck there:

```
rsmd.isWritable(column);
rsmd.isReadOnly(column);
rsmd.isDefinitelyWritable(column);
```

I need to check if it is a virtual column in order to know if i should insert/modify it or not, any ideas?

Comment: That might be DBMS dependent, so looking into the metadata information of the table should help. In case of Oracle, [ALL_TAB_COLS](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8074963/how-to-check-column-is-virtual-in-oracle)

Comment: Find out which actual class the metadata is - you may find it has special methods (beyond those defined for ResultSetMetaData) that can help

Comment: is there any java piece of code that might help?
i checked every method that ResultSetMetaData has and found nothing.

Comment: @HabibGahntous A working piece of Java code is in my answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/77627553/2886891

Answer (score 0):

Like Maheswaran Ravisankar already said, the only way to get this information is to run a query against the database. Maybe there is a Java function which does exactly this operation but I doubt that.
The following query should do it for you:

```
select VIRTUAL_COLUMN from ALL_TAB_COLS where OWNER = :1 and TABLE_NAME = :2 and COLUMN_NAME = :3;
```

The result of the query will be `YES or NO` (YES = column is virtual).

**Remember:** Oracle metadata are usually stored in upper case.

Comment: return Java != SQL; though this would still be helpful I'm sure

Answer (score 0):

It seems absolutely stupid, but after searching internet I really believe that there is no simple Java function for it.

Based on my experience, the functions with otherwise promising names and promising [Javadoc](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/21/docs/api/java.sql/java/sql/ResultSetMetaData.html) return nonsensical values:

| funtion | returns always |
| --- | --- |
| `isReadOnly(column)` | `true` |
| `isWritable(column)` | `true` |
| `isDefinitelyWritable(column)` | `false` |

Based on the [standard documention of `DatabaseMetadata`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/21/docs/api/java.sql/java/sql/DatabaseMetaData.html#getColumns(java.lang.String,java.lang.String,java.lang.String,java.lang.String)) I came with the following Java code. I tested the code on Postgres but as I am using only documented general Java functionality, I believe it will work for Oracle, too.

```java
private static final int COLUMN_NAME = 4;
private static final int IS_GENERATEDCOLUMN = 24;

public Set<String> getCalculatedColumns(Connection connection, String schema, String table) throws SQLException {
    final ResultSet tableMetaData = connection.getMetaData().getColumns(null, schema, table, null);
    final Set<String> calculatedColumns = new HashSet<>();
    while (tableMetaData.next()) {
        if ("YES".equals(tableMetaData.getObject(IS_GENERATEDCOLUMN, String.class))) {
            calculatedColumns.add(tableMetaData.getObject(COLUMN_NAME, String.class));
        }
    }
    return calculatedColumns;
}
```

For explanation of the magic numbers 4 and 24 in the code, look at the above mentioned documentation.